# Find a value for a specific key in a linked hashmap in java

Tags: java, aem, jcr, magnolia

Is there a simpler way to find a value for a specific key in a linked hash map in Java?

```
HashMap<String, Object> newmap = (HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
String newType = "";
//finds out the primaryType for the new node
for (Entry<String, Object> mapentry : newmap.entrySet()) {
    if (mapentry.getKey() == "jcr:primaryType") {
        newType = (String) newmap.get("jcr:primaryType");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's right there in your code: `newmap.get("jcr:primaryType")`. The rest is redundant.

Comment: Basicly everthing except for `newmap.get("jcr:primaryType");` is pointless in the code you posted. Also what you posted will not work because you are trying to compare String using `==`

Comment: Also, your code creates a `HashMap`, not a `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinkedHashMap<String , Object> newmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
String newType = (String) newmap.getOrDefault("jcr:primaryType", "");
```

Comment: I would probably remove the unchecked cast and use `Map<?,?>`

Comment: It's a good practice to declare your data types in the compile-time as far as they're static.

Comment: It is not good practice to have compiler warnings about unchecked casts. It is not good practice to code against `LinkedHashMap` when `Map` will do.

Comment: What do you mean when you say to remove the unchecked cast @Thilo? Map<String , Object> newmap = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue(); also gives me Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Object>

Comment: Yes, you have to use `Map<?,?>`. That is the only safe cast.

Answer (score 4):

Since your default result is `""`, you can do

```
String newType = newmap.getOrDefault("jcr:primaryType", "");
```

Comment: Upvoted because this preserves the original behaviour from the question and `getOrDefault` is good to know. But in real life, having it become `null` might be more natural/better.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are correct if we are talking about pure Map perspective but in JCR or Magnolia; you can use `javax.jcr.Node#getProperty`

To query the Node object for a particular property, one might use; `javax.jcr.Node#hasProperty`

Comment: That is true but I am loading the values from a yaml file using yaml load and it creates a nested map.

Comment: I understand @AnaSustic, then Map operations are the way to go here.